# UIWebView getOrientation always "portrait" on iPad2

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I have a nice running HTML5 Website with some JavaScript. This Page is called in a UIWebView. 
The Page runs some JavaScript to check, weather the iPad is in Portrait or in Landscape Mode.

And here is the Problem. It doesn't matter, if the iPad is in Landscape or in Portrait-Mode, the Function call:

```
orientationObserver.getOrientation()
```

always returns "portrait".

Is this a known Problem, or am i doing something wrong? I set the View containing the UIWebView to landscape mode with:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

i do an:

```
alert(orientationObserver.getOrientation()
```

in the JS and it returns always "Portrait", the device (and so the App) runs in landscape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify CSS styles based on viewport orientation: Target the browser with `body[orient="landscape"] or body[orient="portrait"]`

However Apple's approach to this issue is to allow the developer to change the CSS based on the orientation change but not to prevent re-orientation completely. I found a similar question [here](http://ask.metafilter.com/99784/How-can-I-lock-iPhone-orientation-in-Mobile-Safari).

Comment: The point is, that i can not change something in the HTML / CSS / JS Code that's loaded. The Code is generated by another Software and "only" needs to be displayed in a UIWebView on iPad. If i open the HTML in Safari everything works like a charm.

Comment: My tests on iPhone and iPad do not show a `body[orient="landscape"]` CSS rule having any effect. Rather, there is an example by Joe Hewitt (http://web.archive.org/web/20100408142542/http://www.joehewitt.com/files/liquid1.html) which uses Javascript to *set* an 'orient' attribute to make this technique work. The implication that you can specify CSS rules based on orientation without that Javascript is incorrect, although it's repeated a few places. (Maybe it used to work, or maybe each of those places have copied it from elsewhere without testing.)